# Use ngRoute only on links in route config

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Let's say I have two routes configured, and also an otherwise option with a sepereate controller.

```
$routeProvider.
when('/careers/all', {
    title : 'All Careers',
    templateUrl: '/_get/html/listing,careers_app?action=all',
    controller: 'careersController',
    animation: 'slide'
}).
when('/careers/view/:job*', {
    title : '',
    controller: 'careersController',
    animation: 'slide'
}).otherwise({
    template : ' ',
    controller : 'redirectController'
});
// use the HTML5 History API
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

I just want something to handle everything else so that it acts as a standard anchor would behave, I see that others have added a `target="_self"` to anchors to get this to work, but this is totally impractical as I have hundreds of anchors and I'm not the only one managing this website. I need to get this controller to redirect, but obviously not just continuously loop because the page refreshes, then the otherwise fires, then the page refreshes again, so I've created a recursive refresh.

Controller:

```
_core.controller('redirectController', ['$location', '$window', '$rootScope', function($location, $window, $rootScope) {
    var path = $location.path();
    $window.location.href = path;
}]);
```

What can I do to set this up, is there a way to detect before the route pathname is set? I know theres an event `$routeChangeStart` however the path is already set before this callback is run.

Ideas?

Comment: Objective here is totally unclear. Your `otherwise` would typically be some sort of landing page. Using a controller for redirection really doesn't make much sense. An anchor only `behaves` if the route it points to is valid

Comment: Well, instead of using the otherwise option to redirect to one page, I need it to redirect to any page clicked, not just a single page redirect

Comment: Still not understanding what that means. Provide example of link and expected resultant route

Comment: All links are generated from a cms, like /pagea, /pageb, no hasing is used, using the HTML5 mode, and i've set the base href to /.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. From my understanding you pretend to keep the normal behaviour for anchors while still keeping the pushstate to work.

This is my approach: 
http://jsbin.com/kafoxu/1/edit

I Hope it helps

Comment: Forgive me for being ignorant, but how is the directive called here?

Comment: The directice is an attribute placed at body

Comment: In your jsbin you're not using the intercept directive though?

Comment: Ahh yeah, sorry i did remove the directive temporarely and gave you the wrong version. To make it work you must add link-interceptor to body and inside the directive click event you can write your own logic. But I did understand your question correctly. Your solution is enought.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by completely removing the otherwise option. And adding in an event listener to the `$location` service.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl){
    var hasCareers = newUrl.indexOf("careers/") > -1;
    if (newUrl == oldUrl || hasCareers) return;
    $window.location.href = newUrl;
});
```

Seeing as I only have two routes, both containing careers/ in the url, I simply did a check to see if it was the careers page, or we're already on the page it's trying to change to, so don't update, else trigger a refresh.